# Inserting statements from .sql file into Oracle database resulting ORA-01704: string literal too long

Tags: sql, oracle

I exported some data from my database table into sql file as insert statements.
Now I want to launch them but I get error ORA-01704: string literal too long.
The problem cause is propably one CLOB column which has XML data more than 4000 chars.

What would be the best workaround?
I have about ~50 SQL insert statements in that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using insert statements, you could leave the data in a delimited file and look at using either [SQLLDR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm), or [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm). External tables are awesome.

Comment: Yeah, I've realized that:) But atm I have SQL insert statements only.

Comment: you can convert from an insert statement to a CSV file in about five seconds using a decent text editor and regular expressions! Replace "Insert into (a,b,c) values (" with "" and then replace ");" with "" and you're done. Use regex anchors to make sure you only get the start and end of a line.

Comment: Can you help me with that? Here's an example of one sql insert: Insert into document (document_id,recipient_id,folder_is,data,delete_on,previous_version) values ('766767','12','0','<XML DATA IS HERE>','to_date('22.02.2013 13:15:07','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS'),null);

Comment: what platform are you on? Do you have access to `sed`?

Comment: alternatively, you could a new question post "how to convert SQL insert statements into CSV", you might get a better range of answers!

Comment: Sry for the stupid vuestion how to get them into CSV, I was really tired and lost hope until I took a little break and realized how easy it was really. Later after getting data into CSV used SQLLDR as you recommended. Nicely and easily:)

Answer (score 1):

The way to get something larger then 4000 bytes in is to use pl\sql which supports up to 32767 bytes. Here is an example of how to solve the ORA-01704: string literal too long error:

```
declare
vClobVal varchar2(32767) := '<Add text string here>';
begin
update CLOBTAB set CLOBCOL = vClobVal;
end;
```

you can also change your colomun type from varchar2 to CLOB

also see if this link can help you - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01704_string_literal_too_long.htm

Comment: What if they are bigger than 32767 bytes? Also I have anout 50 insert staments like this: INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, TOO_LONG_VALUE,...)

Comment: @Marko, the [max size of a clob](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html) is 8TB in 9i and 10g and 128TB in 11g. I doubt you're anywhere near the limit. If they're bigger I search for how to use a clob, as it's going to get a little more complicated as you have to read / write multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought for that particular column you should have split columns. For example say you current column is RANDOM_TEXT as VARCHAR(4000) it is exceeding the limit, you can split this into 2 columns say RANDOM_TEXT_1 and RANDOM_TEXT_2, when you are writing you should take the first 4000 characters to first RANDOM_TEXT_1 and the remaining to RANDOM_TEXT_2. When you are giving this back to any app or any api you have to combine and give as a single string.

Comment: I dont use any apps, trying to launch the file in sql*plus.

Comment: what i mean is the data being loaded by you may be used by some other application right, that's what i mentioned. then you may need to have a pl sql to seperate the big clob and put into 2 different columns...that's just a suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it worked for me:

```
DECLARE 
big_text_  CLOB := 'very very very very long text or XML.......';
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3_CLOB) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', big_text_);
  COMMIT;
END;
```